# What is the replacement for start-mapred.sh?

Tags: hadoop

I am reading the book on Hadoop that refers to the script `start-mapred.sh`. I downloaded the latest version of Hadoop, and there is no `start-mapred.sh` script in it.

I see there is `start-yarn.sh` but does it start the `JobTracker` and `TaskTracker` components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yarn is the next version of MapReduce and does not use job and task tracker and instead uses resource manager to do its job. for MRv1 use 2.3.0 version of hadoop. Also the same programs can be run using Yarn. to start hadoop just use `start-all.sh` or `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`

also to access resourcemanager use `<ipaddress>:8088`